# Manipulate SQL statement before execution on server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

Our databases are on SQL Server 2000. We are migrating to SQL Server 2008 R2.

We want to update the compatibility level to 100.

But the join operator `*=` and `=*` are no more supported with that compatibility level.

The advised solution is to update our source code and change the operators to `OUTER JOIN`.

But we cannot afford the modification of thousand exe and dll. So we cannot update our source code; there are too many projects.

My question is:

Is there in SQL Server 2008 R2 any system which will allow me to:

1. catch the SQL statement before it's execution
2. update the statement (for instance replace `*=` by `LEFT OUTER JOIN`)
3. give back the modified statement to the SQL Server engine for execution

This method would allow us to set the compatibility level to 100 even though our programs still use the old syntax

Thanks

(P.S. This question has been cross-posted on [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84459/manipulate-sql-statement-before-execution-on-server))

Comment: Even if that kind of trick is possible, I definitely recommend not to do it ! That's an awful approach that won't help in the long term, I assure you.

Comment: I'm aware of this. If the trick exists, we will use it only for our old projects. Not the new one.

Comment: 'The advised solution is to update our source code and change the operators to OUTER JOINS' - sounds like good advice. It may also be quicker and less error prone than trying to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That would require two things that do not exist:

1. Something akin to an `INSTEAD OF SELECT` trigger

   and
2. 1000 billable hours (or more depending on how good you and/or your team is at QA) to come up with the text parsing / regular expressions / etc needed to capture all of the syntax variations that are allowed in queries: block comments in the middle of values , inline comments at the end, conditions broken up into multiple lines, table aliases, outer joins of inner-joined tables, and so on and so on.

You will actually spend *less* time updating your source code (as others have suggested), even across "thousand exe and dll", than you will trying to implement this and then spending the rest of your life debugging it and taking support calls for problems that eventually turn out to be caused by bugs in this.

(P.S. this answer has been cross-posted on [DBA.StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84540/30859), but with a bit more detail there)

**UPDATE**

I submitted a Microsoft Feedback Suggestion for this ability: [Intercept query batch from client to rewrite it or cancel it](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896183-intercept-query-batch-from-client-to-rewrite-it-or).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that updating the apps would be the right thing to do, long-term.

But sometimes doing the right thing is not an option, and you have to consider alternatives.

In your case,  there is the option to add a smart database proxy (e.g. Gallium Data) to rewrite the query as needed. You can define a filter in the proxy that will intercept the problematic queries and rewrite them as desired. Then all you need is to get those apps to talk to the proxy instead of directly to the database.

Given your problem, is this preferable to modifying all these apps? That's a decision you need to make, given your particular situation. But you have that option.